# Keep Activity on top

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to implement a screenLock activity, which triggers whenever the user locks the screen. 
I did this, but if the user opens the Application History I see two activities of my application: Sensitive-Activity and Lock-Activity.

If the user clicks on the Sensitive-Activity in the stack it comes foreground, without populating the Lock-Activity. By doing this I have some serious security issues here.

Could someone tell me how can I 'pin' Lock-Activity on the top, making it appear even user clicks on other activities?

ps.: noHistroy on Sensitive-Activity is not a solution, since if no lock activated then users can't access to the app once it pushed to the background.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Sensitive"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Lock"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file, remove, launcher tag from sensitive activity.
After that only lock activity will show to user. Current you may have set both activities as launcher activity, therefore you are watching two activities.

Answer (score 0):

By loading Sensitive activity from the background(history) run code to show Lock activity.
You can register and implement Application lifecycle callbacks

```
public class ForegroundWatchdog implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(final Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }
}
```

To register callbacks:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    Context appCtx = getApplicationContext();
    if (appCtx instanceof Application) {
        ForegroundWatchdod foregroundWatchdog = new ForegroundWatchdog();
        Application application = (Application)appCtx;
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(foregroundWatchdog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me!
My only problem with this solution that onDestory will be called both case: when user closed the activity from History OR when I closed the activity, since they entered the password. I can't tell which case happen, because I have to relaunch the activity in the 1st case to prevent access

Comment: I thought that this is exactly what you wanted. so which flow/scenario you want to cover/handle?

Comment: so, my problem that in the recent apps, both activities are visible: Sensitive and Lock. If they close Lock, user can enter to Sensitive without any problem. I tried android:excludeFromRecents="true" on Lock activity, but for whatever reason it doesn't work

Comment: So what the problem with application callbacks to implement logic that will throw user to Lock activity if it destroyed. And generally why you see 2 activities of same app in recent apps?

Comment: #1 if user enters the password I am destroying the Lock activity, which will be detected (false positive) in the lifecycle events.
#2 I have no idea, I shouldn't

info: Sensitive activity has an abstract super class, which I inherit it from

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: keep flag with timestamp in shared preferences if user logged in(entered password) successfully and on Sensitive activity opened check if user entered password and when if no password or timeout more than X minutes throw him to Lock activity...

Comment: this solved the issue:
                    intentToStart.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    intentToStart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Thank you very much for your help @LifeStyle